# Calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: multithreading, powershell, printing

I am trying to retrieve list of print queues from PowerShell as shown below.
But I am getting

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`.

Is it happeneing because PowerShell not being able to support multiple threads?

Is there a way to get around this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please next time put your code as text, not as screen copy, so that other guy can test without typing your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have to start PowerShell with -STA (single thread appartment) parameter to have your code working :

```
PowerShell -STA
Add-Type -AssemblyName  "system.Printing"
$f = @([system.Printing.EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes]::local, [system.Printing.EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes]::shared)
$ps = New-Object system.Printing.localprintserver
$pq = $ps.GetPrintQueues($f)
```