# PowerShell threading

Tags: multithreading, powershell, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900705/calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

I am trying to retrieve list of print queues from PowerShell as shown below.
But I am getting an error as shown below in the picture

Is it happeneing because PowerShell not being able to support multiple threads?

Is there a way to get around this problem?

[image]